# automatic update of Iot Devices Status in to the WPF C# application

Tags: wpf, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have IoT device with status(Idle, Recording, Editing, Saving, Offline) which is updated in the device twin by the device app.

I need to get the device status and show in the WPF c# application automatically in real time.

Current the wpf application is updating by using the IoT query string on button click. but i need to update the status without sending request.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem goes a bit out of the scope of your WPF and requires some backend(cloud) changes.

You can create a message route to send the device twin changed notification. 
[image]

As an endpoint, you can have Event Hub and then Azure Function that is triggered on the message in that Event Hub. There you can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-azure-functions) to publish some information and then [implement](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application) handling that in your WPF.

Comment: We have around 10000 devices registered with different users and if we use Event Hub, the user will get all the device's status. There is security issue. Any other idea.

Comment: No, the EventHub above you are using to route DeviceTwin changed notification messages. That way you can have the dedicated pipeline just for handling that case. In the Azure function(or something else what you maybe prefer more) you just handle these notifications, where you can get a mapping between device Id and associated customer/user of your wpf app, and then use Signal R, for example, to send the message to the dedicated app instance/user associated with that device. This means that you need to have mapping as well from the app side.

Comment: Having deviceIds, users/app assigned in some kind of storage(cosmosdb for example), helps you to isolate and to define which 'channel' you will use in your AF and SignalR to send messages.

Comment: Can you please provide the work flow or sample code or diagram?